# What are these trailing plants with white flowers?

Tags: identification, container-gardening, annuals

I was looking for plants to add to containers along with red geraniums (pelargoniums) and came across this photo but after much searching couldn't find any information on what the white trailing plants in this basket are. Can anyone identify them?

Looks like it might be two different white flowers. The trailing ones in front and then the ones in the back that look a bit like chamomile flowers.

I'd be happy even with something similar. Ideally a trailing annual that I can use in a similar container arrangement with red geraniums that has small white flowers that is preferably not toxic to pets and that I can start from seeds.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white trailing plant to the left is Achillea ptarmica 'Gypsy White'

[image]

[Monrovia's](http://www.monrovia.com/plant-catalog/plants/2586/gypsy-white-yarrow/) Description:

> Abundant tiny, bright white flowers bloom above fragrant, deep green,
>   needle-like foliage on a semi-trailing habit. This butterfly attractor
>   is a wonderful addition to mass plantings, containers or as a
>   specimen. A long-lasting cut flower. Very heat tolerant. Perennial.

[Further Info](http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/achillea-ptarmica-gipi-whi-gypsy-white-pp18120/)

[Awards](https://www.provenwinners.com/plants/awards/44974)

[Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achillea_ptarmica) entry for this plant lists its species as [toxic to equines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plants_poisonous_to_equines) but it doesn't actually appear any longer on the list itself.

The small leaf that appears under the daisies to the right indicate to me a cultivar of Marguerite. More than likely, Argyranthemum frutescens as shown here on the [Proven Winnners](https://www.provenwinners.com/plants/argyranthemum/molimba-helio-white-marguerite-daisy-argyranthemum-frutescens) website.

[image]

Comment: That looks right. Any idea about the white flowers in the back?

Comment: I was worried the first may not be trailing but according to the following link it is a trailing plant (shown in hanging basket) and is used in place of bacopa where heat is a concern. http://www.greenhousecanada.com/crops/flowers/growing-in-the-green-testing-garden-performance-part-two-3001

Answer (score 2):

I have found a flower that may suit your needs, looks similar but is not the same. It is called 'Bacopa'. They come in white, pink, lavender, blue, coral red. These are annual and have flowers almost all year. Look more into these if you want but I think these will do you well.

Here's an example of red geraniums with white bacopa.

[image]

Image from http://www.indianapolisorchard.com/

Comment: This looks like a good choice. Do you happen to know if they're toxic to pets? I found seeds for Snowtopia Bacopa and that looks like it will work. https://www.harrisseeds.com/Storefront/p-9470-bacopa-snowtopia-white-mplt.aspx

Comment: I think so, my pets have nibbled on it and have not died or got sick (cat, dog)

Comment: Wasn't sure what to do here. I'm accepting Brenn's answer because it looks like he got the identification correct. I'm probably going to go with Bacopa though since I'm having a hard time finding the other seeds.